# Problem with Arduino and 2 Sharp IR sensors

Tags: arduino, sensor, infrared, distance

I have 1 Arduino and 2 IR Sharp [GP2Y0A02YK0F proximity sensors](http://www.sharpsma.com/webfm_send/1487), I connected 1 sensor, with mounted capacitors between GND and VCC (100nF, 10000nF)

Everything is fine, I have good values, *but* when I connect the second sensor, both get electrically disturbed.

I get strange values from both sensors.  What can I do that I get good Values of both sensors with 1 Arduino board?

Comment: What's the part number of the sensors (or post a link to the datasheet)?  In what way do they get electrically disturbed?

Comment: How are you connecting these sensors? Can you provide a wiring diagram?

Comment: The Sensors i use are this one: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8958 , I connected them parallel to the 5V pin on the Arduino and the GND Pin on the Arduino, the output of the sensors go to pin 5 and pin 4 of the analog in pins of the arduino. I dont know in what way they got disturbed, i only get messy values when i connect them both on the arduino :/ hope u guys can help me

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the two sensors get cross interference, since they both work with IR beams. If you have to use them in parallel make sure they are pointing in different directions. Alternatively you can implement a switching algorithm on your Arduino. That is to turn on the first sensor, take measurement then turn off and then repeat with the next sensor. This way there will be no cross interference even if the point at the same location.

Comment: The Sensors are pointing in different directions, thats not the problem i think. How can i realize a switching algorithm, with relais? thx

Comment: There could still be some cross interference from reflections so I think you should test out switching and see how it performs. For switching, you can use an NPN transistor in the common emitter layout. Make sure you saturate the transistor to allow maximum voltage across the sensor.

Comment: You should be able to test for possible interferences simply by entirely covering one of the sensor with some opaque material.